Feynman diagrams where $\pi^+$ and $\pi^-$ are exchanged


I am looking at Feynman diagrams where these two vertices with a $\pi^+$ and a $\pi^-$ appear. It is a $I_3=-1/2$ to $I_3=1/2$ transition, are these vertices the same since $\pi^-$ is the antiparticle to $\pi^+$ or is there additional stuff to consider?
If we look at the matrix which gives the coeffcients for and Isospin 1/2-to-3/2 transition matrices required
$$     T^+=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(T^1+iT^2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &\sqrt{3}
\end{pmatrix}, $$
the matrix which increases $I_3$ by 1 has only an entry for a $\pi^+$, so I assume an outgoing $\pi^-$ is treated as an incoming $\pi^+$? Does that mean every diagram containing an virtual $\pi^+$ is the same as that diagram but with an opposite $\pi^-$?

It isn't immediately clear to me that the diagram on the right is valid - the charge of the $\Delta^0$ is zero and the charge of the proton is one, so the only valid decay is by a negatively-charged particle or by a neutral particle into a neutron instead (pions in both cases). See the Wikipedia page which helpfully cites sources for the $\Delta^0$ decays. which seems to include the left diagram but not the right one.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Line reversal amounts to charge conjugation. Review your textbook.
